# How to use a comparison statement on a for loop iterator in a conditional statement?

Tags: python

I'm iterating over a large (300+ columns & 1 000 000+ rows) .txt file (tab delimited). 
file format:

```
species 1    ...    sample1(11th col)    sample2    ....    sampleN(353th col)
species 2    ...    6046                 5364               ....
species 3    ...    15422                0                  ....
```

Each row is a species and from column 11 onward each column is a sample. For each sample I want to know how many species in that sample have a value of greater than 0. So what I do is iterate over each line, see for which samples the value is greater than 0, and if so add a 1. So for each sample the total sum of 1s is the total amount of rows that have a value greater than 0.

For that I use following code:

```
samples = []
OTUnumber = []

with open('all.16S.uniq.txt','r') as file:
     for i,line in enumerate(file): 
        columns = line.strip().split('\t')[11:353] 
        if i == 0: #headers are sample names so first row
            samples = columns #save sample names 
            OTUnumbers = [0 for s in samples] #set starting value as zero
        else:
            for n,v in enumerate(columns):
                if v > 0:
                    OTUnumber[n] = OTUnumber[n] + 1
                else:
                    continue

result = dict(zip(samples,OTUnumbers))
```

When I run thise code I get following error:
`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`
This error is raised by `if v > 0`. Why can't I write this statement?

So if v of columns [n] > 0 I want to add 1 to OTUnumber at that index. If v <0 I want to skip that row and do not add 1 (or add 0).

How can I make this code work?

Comment: Try int(v) > 0:

Comment: Check the `type()` of `v` please.

Comment: The exception is telling you that ``v`` is a str, so maybe use ``if int(v) > 0:`` instead?

Comment: if int(v)>0 It returns error: ```OTUnumber[n] = OTUnumber[n] + 1

IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: type of v is ```str```. Why does it do this? For me it does not make sense that Python would automatically give such a value the type str.

Comment: @Robvh, you are mixing up `OTUnumber` and `OTUnumbers` in your code.

Comment: @Robvh it's a text file... everything in it is a `str`. some  more complicated data libraries might infer the type based on content, but python is right here...

Comment: Instead of manually parsing a tab-separated file, consider using the `csv` module. `reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter="\t")`, then `next(reader, None)  # skip headers`, and then `for row in reader: row = row[11:353]`. Create `OTUnumbers` as `OTUnumbers = [0] * 342`.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 thanks, I thought Python would infer the type.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why would I consider this? What is the advantage?

Comment: @Robvh: faster, handles edgecases like quoting and newlines in values, lets you switch the dialect later without having to learn how to split different dialect formats, self-documenting (it states to anyone reading you are handling a character-separated file format).

Comment: Also, drop the `else: continue`. `else` is not mandatory, and without the `continue` the loop will still continue, regardless.

Comment: @Robvh: Ah, you are actually producing a dictionary. Use `DictReader()` and you get the column names for free.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can understand your point, but I'm a relatively new python user and for me it clarifies the code.

Comment: You are always free to re-invent the wheel, sure. I'm merely pointing you to a better implementation of that wheel that is available in the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run thise code I get following error: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` This error is raised by if `v > 0`. Why can't I write this statement?

As the error says, you are trying to use the comparison operator `>` on a string and an int, which is not allowed. `v` is a string, not an integer. Presumably you want to use `int(v) > 0` rather than `v > 0`, or do the following to begin with.

```
columns = [int(v) for v in line.strip().split('\t')[11:353]]
```

Comment: Other comments above noted the same but now I get following error: ```OTUnumber[n] = OTUnumber[n] + 1

IndexError: list index out of range```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```py
samples = []
OTUnumbers = []

with open('all.16S.uniq.txt','r') as file:
     for i,line in enumerate(file): 
        columns = line.strip().split('\t')[11:353] 
        if i == 0: #headers are sample names so first row
            samples = columns #save sample names 
            OTUnumbers = [0 for s in samples] #set starting value as zero
        else:
            for n,v in enumerate(columns):
                if int(v) > 0:
                    OTUnumbers[n] = OTUnumbers[n] + 1
                else:
                    continue

result = dict(zip(samples,OTUnumbers))
```

that's basically 2 fixes:

- casting `v` to `int`
- renaming `OTUnumber` to `OTUnumbers` in all the code

Answer (score 1):

So the thing is that in your text file there are records which are strings and your code is trying to compare an integer to a string which throws a TypeError exception

To make the code work you can convert your record to int before comparing i.e, `int(v) > 0`